# Get all the Casefeeds for a user in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, case, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I want to create custom notification component for a lightning community where display all the case comments added by others for the cases created by a logged user. I tried with following methods and was not success.

```
ConnectApi.FeedElementPage userFeedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed(Network.getNetworkId(), ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me', null, 25, ConnectApi.FeedSortOrder.LastModifiedDateDesc);

ConnectApi.FeedElementPage CaseFeedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFilterFeed(Network.getNetworkId(),
                'me', '500', null, 25, ConnectApi.FeedSortOrder.LastModifiedDateDesc);
```

What are the other solutions I can try for this.

Answer (score 0):

I could complete this by using getFeedElementBatch(communityId, feedElementIds) method in ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds